# Searching for neighboring cells

Tags: excel

I am dealing with a large data set in Excel and need to search a for two neighboring cells in the same column.  Usually I would just go through this quickly row by row, but there are around 30,000 rows and probably 1% of those are the neighbors I am looking for.  The data is organized temporally, meaning I cannot just sort.

Anyone have an idea if/how this can be done?

Comment: Duplicates? If so, conditional formatting?

Comment: What is a "neighboring cell" exactly?

Comment: Yes, duplicates.  Each cell will have the same string.  With "neighboring cells," I mean two cells that are adjacent to one-another in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

You could drag down this formula in column next to your data.

For example, in B3 where column A has data:

```
=IF(AND(A3<>"",A2<>""),"neighbour above","")
```

So:

```
    Row  A        B
    1    Data   Check
    2    10 
    3    20     neighbour above
    4   
    5   40  
    6   50      neighbour above
    7   60      neighbour above
    8   
    9   
   10  90
```

Note B2 first position has no formula. This will highlight neighbouring cells within the column.

**How many?**
To count how many neighbours, use a `countif`. so in C1 you can have:

`=COUNTIF(B:B, "neighbour above")`

which will return 3 in this case above. pairs 10 and 20, 40 and 50, 50 and 60.

You can choose other marker text to flag the neighbour, besides "neighbour above". Just put it in the `IF` statement.

Comment: How do you know neighbor means not blank?

Comment: @tbransford has not been clear what he means by neighbouring but I am assuming he has a large block of data with gaps. If he needs equal neighbours then he can use does A3=A3 in the IF statement.